# Sorting all values of an array in a HTML table

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that includes some other arrays. All values which are inside that array, should be placed in a HTML table. I get all the values but my HTML table looks horrible!

I have a code that looks like this:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'name' => array('Tom', 'Robert', 'Julia'),
    'age' => array(32, 45, 21),
    'city' => array('New York', 'Toronto', 'Los Angeles')
);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>City</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
            foreach($data as $values) {
                foreach($values as $value) {
                    echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The output of this code will be:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>City</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>Julia</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>Toronto</td>
    <td>Los Angeles</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is exactly the output that I need:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>City</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>New York</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>Toronto</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Julia</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>Los Angeles</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't really know PHP but the solution seems as simple as wrapping the inner for loop with more echos. ie `echo ... foreach(...) {...} echo...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution with `array_map` function:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'name' => array('Tom', 'Robert', 'Julia'),
    'age' =>  array(32, 45, 21),
    'city' => array('New York', 'Toronto', 'Los Angeles')
);

$items = array_map(null, $data['name'], $data['age'], $data['city']);
?>
<table border='1'>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>City</th></tr>
    <?php
        foreach ($items as $v) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $v) . '</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

The output (push **Run code snippet** button):

```html
<table border="1">
    <tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>City</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Tom</td><td>32</td><td>New York</td></tr><tr><td>Robert</td><td>45</td><td>Toronto</td></tr><tr><td>Julia</td><td>21</td><td>Los Angeles</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Consider reformatting of the `$data` array to keep related values close together. It will make your `foreach` then easier.

```
  $data = array(
  array('name' => 'Tom', 'age' => 32, 'city' => 'New York'),
  array('name' => 'Robert', 'age' => 45, 'city' => 'Toronto'),
  //...
  );
```

This way you get the one table data row within one iteration of `foreach`.